# nerdtree auto focus to file when opened in new tab

Tags: nerdtree, vim

I am using NerdTree on Linux . I would like to jump from the nerd tree buffer to the file buffer after opening a file in a new tab using 't'. 
I need to press 'Ctrl+W+W' all the time.

Any idea about how to have vi execute C-W-W after a new buffer is created .

Sairam

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Simply add `autocmd BufNew * wincmd l` to your .vimrc

Comment: For future travelers: This doesn't work for me (vim 7.2), but putting PaulP's solution in .vimrc after the the line `autocmd vimenter * NERDTree` did the trick

Comment: Yohann's solution worked for me, not this one. Not sure if this is out of date or not, but definitely is very similar.

Answer (score 93):

When vim starts, it opens a window for the file, then it opens another window for `NerdTree`.

The easiest way to come back to the main window is just to jump to the previous window like this:

```
" Start NERDTree
autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree
" Go to previous (last accessed) window.
autocmd VimEnter * wincmd p
```

Comment: exactly what i needed! when opening a file with vim, this sets focus to the newly opened file while still opening NERDTree

Comment: You can combine commands: `autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree | wincmd p`

Comment: perfect thanks got here by searching `vimenter window`

Comment: This works actually. Combining as @NARKOZ says doesn't works for me, not sure why.

Comment: to make NERDTree open on startup and stay focus on nerdtree if no files specified

```autocmd StdinReadPre * let s:std_in=1
autocmd VimEnter * if argc() == 0 && !exists("s:std_in") | NERDTree | else | NERDTree | wincmd p | endif
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use so-called **autocommands**, like:

```
  au BufNew * <command>
```

It will execute *command* when new buffer is created. Start from there. Check out
[vimdoc](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html) on the subject.